# SQL multiple GROUP BY represented in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question is being asked from the SQL Server environment. I have found several suggestions here for creating a query that incorporates multiple `GROUP BY` criteria, but all are producing multiple rows based on the second group criteria. For example if my dataset in the table TrendingData looks like:

```
ID  SEND    HL7 MessageControl                              STAT    DATE CREATED            DATE UPDATED
4   AMC1    A03 A03918604B6-4272-40E6-9178-1D711FB135461    P       2015-12-15 12:01:19.153 2015-12-15 12:01:20.137
5   AMC1    A08 A08918604B6-4272-40E6-9178-1D711FB135462    P       2015-12-15 12:01:20.137 2015-12-15 12:01:20.153
6   UHC1R   A08 A0893126369-10D1-4506-9A42-B9A7E0AC96151    R       2015-12-15 12:01:34.433 2015-12-15 12:01:34.497
7   UHC1R   A03 A03C2468021-8C66-4BAD-A6A7-CBCA02125D411    R       2015-12-15 12:02:38.293 2015-12-15 12:02:38.450
8   UHC1R   A08 A08C2468021-8C66-4BAD-A6A7-CBCA02125D412    P       2015-12-15 12:02:38.450 2015-12-15 12:02:38.760
9   UHC1    A08 A0863D0A3D8-402C-4377-9C77-63518A42A11D1    P       2015-12-15 12:02:42.730 2015-12-15 12:02:43.057
```

Then the result of the query

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(*) AS Counts,
    STAT,
    CONVERT(CHAR(5), DateCreated, 10) AS Date
FROM
    TrendingData
GROUP BY 
    STAT, CONVERT(CHAR(5), DateCreated, 10)
ORDER BY 
    Date;
```

returns output like (and these numbers are from the entire table's dataset, not just the few rows above):

```
Counts  STAT    Date
4488    P       12-15
27568   R       12-15
```

But what I'd rather have is output that looks like:

```
Total   CodeP   CodeR   Date
32056   4488    27568   12-15
```

I'm fairly sure that the `CodeP` column would be populated by some variant of `count(*) from TrendingDate where STAT = 'P'`, but I can't seem to get the syntax right to have the query pull three counts within the same date.

Suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  For a first question, you did a very good job of communicating your problem statement clearly. Well done.

Comment: Are `P` and `R` the only possible values for `STAT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use a `CASE` statement inside your `COUNT` aggregate function for the `P` and `R` counts, and remove the `STAT` column from the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN stat = 'P' THEN 1 END) AS CodeP,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN stat = 'R' THEN 1 END) AS CodeR,
        CONVERT(CHAR(5), DateCreated, 10) AS Date
FROM    TrendingData
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(5), DateCreated, 10)
ORDER BY Date;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize what CASE was doing for me, so I didn't understand how it could e used. I need to read up on that; I'm obviously missing an important tool!